# error: missing template arguments before 'words'

Tags: c++

This is a program that reads in 15 words from the user and runs them through a hash algorithm before storing them in an array. The hashes are then displayed to the user, and the user can query the array for a specific word. When I try running it, I get the follow compilation errors:

```
    11    error: missing template arguments before 'words'
    11    error: expected ';' before 'words'
    21    error: 'words' was not declared in this scope
    27    error: 'words' was not declared in this scope
```

The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    string input;
    hash words; //from class hash defined below
    bool query;
    bool found;

    cout<<"Please enter 15 words to be stored in a database."<<endl;

    for(x = 1; x <= 15; x++)
    {
        cout<<"Word "<<x<<": ";
        cin>>input; //new word
        words.addHash(input); //calls addHash function in hash class
    }

    cout<<"Here are the hashes: "<<endl;
    words.display(); //calls display function in hash class

    cout<<"You can now query the database for a specific word. To stop, type 'stop'."<<endl;
    //search words database
    do
    {
        cout<<"Query: ";
        cin>>input;

        //more specifically, this calls search function to query words   for <user_input>
        if (input != "stop")
        {
            found = words.search(input);
            if (found == true)
            {
                cout<<"Yes, that word was found in the database."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"No, that word was NOT found in the database." <<endl;
            };
        }
        else
        {
            query = false;
        };


    } while ((query) && (input != "stop"));

    return 0;
};

class hash {

private:

    int y;
    std::string hashes[23];
    std::string newHash;
    char first_letter;
    char last_letter;
    int location;
    int z;
    std::string queryHash;
    bool found;

public:

    //first, the constructor for the hash algorithm
    hash()
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 23; y++)
        {
            hashes[y] = "_";
        }
    };


    void addHash(std::string newHash)
    {
        first_letter = newHash.at(0);
        last_letter = newHash.at(newHash.size() - 1);

        location = ((((int)first_letter) + ((int)last_letter)) % 23);

        do
        {
            if (location == 23)
            {
                location = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                location = location + 1;
            }

            hashes[location] = newHash;

        } while (hashes[location] != "_");

    };

    //prints out ALL contents of the 'database'
    void display()
    {
        for (z = 0; z < 23; z++)
        {
            cout<<hashes[z]<<endl;
        }
    };

    //searches the 'database' for the specific word
    bool search(std::string queryHash)
    {
        first_letter = queryHash.at(0);
        last_letter = queryHash.at(queryHash.size() - 1);

        location = ((((int)first_letter) + ((int)last_letter)) % 23);  

        do
        {
            if (location == 23)
            {
                location = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                location = location + 1;
            }

            hashes[location] = newHash;

        } while ((hashes[location] != "_") && (hashes[location] != queryHash));

        if (hashes[location] == queryHash)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            found = false;
        }
        return found;
    };
};
```

**UPDATE:** I modifyed the code as below, but still getting the same error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class hash; //forward declaration

int main()
{
    int x;
    string input;
    hash words; //from class hash defined below
    bool query;
    bool found;

    cout<<"Please enter 15 words to be stored in a database."<<endl;

    for(x = 1; x <= 15; x++)
    {
        cout<<"Word "<<x<<": ";
        cin>>input; //new word
        words.addHash(input); //calls addHash function in hash class
    }

    cout<<"Here are the hashes: "<<endl;
    words.display(); //calls display function in hash class

    cout<<"You can now query the database for a specific word. To stop, type 'stop'."<<endl;
    //search words database
    do
    {
        cout<<"Query: ";
        cin>>input;

        //more specifically, this calls search function to query words   for <user_input>
        if (input != "stop")
        {
            found = words.search(input);
            if (found == true)
            {
                cout<<"Yes, that word was found in the database."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"No, that word was NOT found in the database." <<endl;
            };
        }
        else
        {
            query = false;
        };


    } while ((query) && (input != "stop"));

    return 0;
};

class hash {

private:

    int y;
    std::string hashes[23];
    std::string newHash;
    char first_letter;
    char last_letter;
    int location;
    int z;
    std::string queryHash;
    bool found;

public:

    //first, the constructor for the hash algorithm
    hash()
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 23; y++)
        {
            hashes[y] = "_";
        }
    };


    void addHash(std::string newHash)
    {
        first_letter = newHash.at(0);
        last_letter = newHash.at(newHash.size() - 1);

        location = ((((int)first_letter) + ((int)last_letter)) % 23);

        do
        {
            if (location == 23)
            {
                location = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                location = location + 1;
            }

            hashes[location] = newHash;

        } while (hashes[location] != "_");

    };

    //prints out ALL contents of the 'database'
    void display()
    {
        for (z = 0; z < 23; z++)
        {
            cout<<hashes[z]<<endl;
        }
    };

    //searches the 'database' for the specific word
    bool search(std::string queryHash)
    {
        first_letter = queryHash.at(0);
        last_letter = queryHash.at(queryHash.size() - 1);

        location = ((((int)first_letter) + ((int)last_letter)) % 23);  

        do
        {
            if (location == 23)
            {
                location = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                location = location + 1;
            }

            hashes[location] = newHash;

        } while ((hashes[location] != "_") && (hashes[location] != queryHash));

        if (hashes[location] == queryHash)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            found = false;
        }
        return found;
    };
};
```

Comment: hash isn't defined when you declare it in main.  You need to forward declare the class.

Answer (score 0):

The name `hash` conflicted with `std::hash`.

To correct this,

1. Stop using `using namespace std;`
2. Add `std::` to each identifiers from namespace `std` or add declaration like `using std::cin;` for each identifiers instead of `using namespace std;`

**UPDATE:** Your code should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

// delcaration of a class
class hash {

private:

    int y;
    std::string hashes[23];
    std::string newHash;
    char first_letter;
    char last_letter;
    int location;
    int z;
    std::string queryHash;
    bool found;

public:
    hash();
    void addHash(std::string newHash);
    void display();
    bool search(std::string queryHash);
};

int main()
{
    int x;
    string input;
    hash words; //from class hash defined below
    bool query;
    bool found;

    cout<<"Please enter 15 words to be stored in a database."<<endl;

    for(x = 1; x <= 15; x++)
    {
        cout<<"Word "<<x<<": ";
        cin>>input; //new word
        words.addHash(input); //calls addHash function in hash class
    }

    cout<<"Here are the hashes: "<<endl;
    words.display(); //calls display function in hash class

    cout<<"You can now query the database for a specific word. To stop, type 'stop'."<<endl;
    //search words database
    do
    {
        cout<<"Query: ";
        cin>>input;

        //more specifically, this calls search function to query words   for <user_input>
        if (input != "stop")
        {
            found = words.search(input);
            if (found == true)
            {
                cout<<"Yes, that word was found in the database."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"No, that word was NOT found in the database." <<endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            query = false;
        }


    } while ((query) && (input != "stop"));

    return 0;
}

// below are definitions of member functions

//first, the constructor for the hash algorithm
hash::hash()
{
    for (y = 0; y < 23; y++)
    {
        hashes[y] = "_";
    }
}

void hash::addHash(std::string newHash)
{
    first_letter = newHash.at(0);
    last_letter = newHash.at(newHash.size() - 1);

    location = ((((int)first_letter) + ((int)last_letter)) % 23);

    do
    {
        if (location == 23)
        {
            location = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            location = location + 1;
        }

        hashes[location] = newHash;

    } while (hashes[location] != "_");

}

//prints out ALL contents of the 'database'
void hash::display()
{
    for (z = 0; z < 23; z++)
    {
        cout<<hashes[z]<<endl;
    }
}

//searches the 'database' for the specific word
bool hash::search(std::string queryHash)
{
    first_letter = queryHash.at(0);
    last_letter = queryHash.at(queryHash.size() - 1);

    location = ((((int)first_letter) + ((int)last_letter)) % 23);  

    do
    {
        if (location == 23)
        {
            location = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            location = location + 1;
        }

        hashes[location] = newHash;

    } while ((hashes[location] != "_") && (hashes[location] != queryHash));

    if (hashes[location] == queryHash)
    {
        found = true;
    }
    else
    {
        found = false;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand. I edited the code according to my interpretation. Is this sufficient or am I still missing something?

Comment: @OxNightRo Rollbacked not to break the question. It isn't sufficient.

Comment: Ahh okay, I understand now. I made changes and ran the program. However, it got rid of the first error on line 11. However, I still got the same pre existing errors.

Comment: @OxNightRo What you did is declaration of a function, not an declaration of a class.

Comment: Now it's compiling, but after I enter the first word in, it hangs. What could be causing this?

Comment: You overwrote `hashes[location]`  by `newHash` in function `hash::addHash()`, then loop while `hashes[location] != "_"`. It means you won't get out of this loop unless you enter `_` as word or you are lucky: this code may access `hashes[23]`, which is not allocated and must not be accessed.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation as to what would fix this?